# Problem while passing data to child component using props in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuex, vue-props

I'm new to Vue Js and facing an issue.
I am using Axios to get users' data with [JSON placeholder API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/).
In the `Sidebar component`.
I used getters to get the users' data from the Vuex store. Inside the `Sidebar component`, I have a child component named `User` which will be created for each user passing in the loop.
I am passing user data to the `User component` in a loop via props, but there seems an error while accessing props.
Here is the error-

[image: error]

Here is my code-

**Sidebar.vue-**
`

```
<template>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar__info">
            <p class="sidebar__title">Поиск сотрудников</p>
            <input class="sidebar__input"/>
            <p class="results">Результаты</p>
            <div  class="results__info" v-for="users in allUsers" key="users.id" >
                <User :users="users"/>
             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import User from "./User.vue"

export default {
    components: {
        User
    }, 
   computed: {
    allUsers () {
        return this.$store.getters.allUsers;
    }
   },
   async mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsers')
   }
}

</script>
```

**Vuex store-**
`

```
import axios from "axios";

export const userModule = {
  state: () => ({
    users: [],
    isUsersLoading: false,
  }),
  getters: {
    displayUsers: (state) => state.users,
  },
  mutations: {
    setUsers(state, users) {
      state.users = users;
    },
    setLoading(state, bool) {
      state.isUsersLoading = bool;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchUsers({ state, commit }) {
      try {
        commit("setLoading", true);
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"
        );
        commit("setUsers", response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } finally {
        commit("setLoading", false);
      }
    },
  },
  modules: {},
};
```

**User.vue-**
`

```
<template>
    <div class="user">
        <div class="user__block">
            <div class="user__img">
                <img src="../assets/img/Rectangle 4.svg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="user__info">
                <p class="user__name">{{users.name}}</p>
                <p class="user__email">Sincere@april.biz</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

  export default {
    props: users
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be great.

In the user component, I changed the props as you said. In the sidebar component, I changed the getter because it refers to itself. I didn't make any more changes. There was an error
User component is not rendered at all, but it needs to be rendered relative to the number of objects in the request

[image: sidebar]

[image: user]

[image: new error]

Comment: The syntax of props is not correct. Use, props: ["users"]

Comment: Props in your User component need to be an array or an object, see: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Comment: User component is not rendered because allUsers is [] (empty) when rendered. You could wrap it with an `v-if=!setLoading`, so when the api call is done and you have data, User would render

Comment: why allUsers is [] (empty) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the props in the right way.
The correct way to access props in any component is either in an array format or an object format. For example-

**First way-**

```
props: ["users"]
```

**Second way-**

```
props: {
  users: {
    required: true // depends if the prop is required or not.
    type: Object // It can be any data type
  }
}
```

The second way is best to follow as it comes with validations. You can read more about passing and accessing props here-

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Comment: The problem is that the User component is not rendered at all. And i have this error - ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: But you mentioned the error in User.vue component.

Comment: If an error is different then please edit your question with the proper error screenshot.

Comment: I have added the changes to the bottom of the post